# Java erro ao inserir imagem em planilha. Apache Poi

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

Estou tentando inserir uma imagem em uma folha usando Apache POI , mas eu estou recebendo o seguinte erro :

```
03-03 20:21:50.898: E/SELinux(28413): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: Error reading /seapp_contexts, line 16, name levelFrom, value container
03-03 20:21:50.908: D/dalvikvm(28413): Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-03 20:21:51.668: D/libEGL(28413): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so
03-03 20:21:51.678: D/libEGL(28413): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno.so
03-03 20:21:51.708: D/libEGL(28413): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:316>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_3.2_RB3.04.03.00.134.050_msm8610_JB_3.2_RB3__release_AU ()
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 20.00.02
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): Build Date: 11/12/13 Tue
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): Local Branch: 
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): Remote Branch: quic/jb_3.2_rb3.21
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): Local Patches: NONE
03-03 20:21:51.718: I/Adreno-EGL(28413): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_3.2_RB3.04.03.00.134.050 + NOTHING
03-03 20:21:51.978: D/OpenGLRenderer(28413): Enabling debug mode 0
03-03 20:21:52.518: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(28413): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection
03-03 20:21:52.528: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(28413): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-03 20:21:52.538: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(28413): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
03-03 20:21:52.538: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(28413): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
03-03 20:21:58.468: E/SpannableStringBuilder(28413): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-03 20:21:58.468: E/SpannableStringBuilder(28413): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-03 20:21:58.978: E/SpannableStringBuilder(28413): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-03 20:21:58.978: E/SpannableStringBuilder(28413): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
03-03 20:22:02.368: D/dalvikvm(28413): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 235K, 11% free 9609K/10696K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-03 20:22:02.418: D/dalvikvm(28413): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11K, 9% free 10061K/10972K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
03-03 20:22:02.458: D/dalvikvm(28413): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9K, 8% free 10532K/11424K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
03-03 20:22:02.928: D/dalvikvm(28413): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 734K, 13% free 11166K/12760K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
03-03 20:22:03.398: W/dalvikvm(28413): Exception Ljava/lang/RuntimeException; thrown while initializing Lorg/apache/poi/ddf/DefaultEscherRecordFactory;
03-03 20:22:03.398: D/AndroidRuntime(28413): Shutting down VM
03-03 20:22:03.398: W/dalvikvm(28413): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d23898)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3839)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4476)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18795)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3834)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): ... 11 more
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.AbstractEscherHolderRecord.convertToEscherRecords(AbstractEscherHolderRecord.java:78)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.AbstractEscherHolderRecord.convertRawBytesToEscherRecords(AbstractEscherHolderRecord.java:73)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.DrawingGroupRecord.processChildRecords(DrawingGroupRecord.java:79)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.InternalWorkbook.findDrawingGroup(InternalWorkbook.java:2051)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.initDrawings(HSSFWorkbook.java:1588)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.addPicture(HSSFWorkbook.java:1608)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at pro.kondratev.androidreadxlsx.ReadXlsx.criar(ReadXlsx.java:136)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): ... 14 more
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: RECORD_ID
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at org.apache.poi.ddf.DefaultEscherRecordFactory.recordsToMap(DefaultEscherRecordFactory.java:135)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at org.apache.poi.ddf.DefaultEscherRecordFactory.<clinit>(DefaultEscherRecordFactory.java:42)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): ... 21 more
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: RECORD_ID
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at java.lang.Class.getField(Class.java:673)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): at org.apache.poi.ddf.DefaultEscherRecordFactory.recordsToMap(DefaultEscherRecordFactory.java:129)
03-03 20:22:03.428: E/AndroidRuntime(28413): ... 22 more
```

O Código é:

```
public void criar (View view) throws IOException {

    String nome = ((String) txtnome.getText().toString());
    String foto = ((String) txtstring.getText().toString());

    FileInputStream input_document = new FileInputStream(new File("sdcard/projetos/enguelber/formulario.xls"));
    HSSFWorkbook my_xls_workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(input_document); 
    HSSFSheet sheet = my_xls_workbook.getSheetAt(0); 

    // Nome do cliente
    Row row = sheet.getRow(7);
    Cell cell = row.getCell(1);
    String cliente = ((String) txtcliente.getText().toString());

    cell.setCellValue(cliente); 

    // CPF do cliente
    Row row1 = sheet.getRow(7);
    Cell cell1 = row.getCell(7);
    String cpf = ((String) txtcpf.getText().toString());

        cell1.setCellValue(cpf); 

     // Hora

        String hora = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        Row row2 = sheet.getRow(35);

        Cell cell2 = row2.getCell(1);
        cell2.setCellValue(hora);

        // Foto do relatorio

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("sdcard/projetos/enguelber/fotos/02.03.2016 21.15.27.jpg");

        byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

        int pictureIdx = my_xls_workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);

        inputStream.close();

        CreationHelper helper = my_xls_workbook.getCreationHelper();

        Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

        ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
        anchor.setCol1(1);
        anchor.setRow1(2);

        Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);

        pict.resize();

       // foto
      //  Row row3 = sheet.getRow(13);
   //     Cell cell3 = row3.getCell(1);

     //   cell3.setCellValue(foto); 

       input_document.close();
       FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File("sdcard/projetos/enguelber/"+ nome + ".xls"));

        my_xls_workbook.write(output_file);

        output_file.close();

    }
```

Se eu remover as linhas onde insiro a imagem o aplicativo roda normalmente.

Bibliotecas:

aa-poi-3.10-min-0.1.5

aa-poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-reduced-more-0.1.5

commons-codec-1.7

poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-reduced-less

ooxml-schemas-1.0

Comment: O erro diz que não está encontrando um determinado atributo numa classe do Apache POI. Eu não investiguei em detalhes, mas se uma classe do POI não encontra um atributo esperado em outra da mesma biblioteca, poderia ser o caso de você estar incluindo dependências de diferentes versões da mesma biblioteca. Verifique suas dependências, edite a sua pergunta e coloque a versão de cada jar do POI que está no seu classpath.

Comment: @utluiz boa noite muito obrigado pela colaboração, conforme solicitado adicionei as informações ao tópico.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consegui solucionar o problema, removendo as bibliotecas listadas acima e por fim adicionei as bibliotecas a baixo:

**poi-3.11**

**commons-codec-1.9**

No código não foi necessário realizar nenhuma alteração.
Grato

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com as informações da [documentação](https://poi.apache.org/overview.html) as versões das suas dependências parecem ser incompatíveis.

Lá diz o seguinte:

> ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar for POI 3.14 or later, ooxml-schemas-1.1.jar for POI 3.7 up to POI 3.13, ooxml-schemas-1.0.jar for POI 3.5 and 3.6

Basicamente significa que se você está usando POI 3.10 significa que deveria estar usando `ooxml-schemas-1.1` e não a versão `1.0` como na sua lista.

Entretanto, notei que está usando uma [versão customizada para o Android](https://github.com/andruhon/AndroidReadXLSX) e na documentação diz que `aa-poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-reduced-more-0.1.5.jar` já contém `ooxml-schemas` embutido no jar, então você não precisaria desse jar. Portanto a versão `1.0` no seu classpath está causando conflitos.

A solução mais simples, ao que parece, seria simplesmente remover `ooxml-schemas-1.0` e deixar somente as outras.

Além disso, o jar `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-reduced-less` parece ser redundante. Remova-o também.

Se nada disso funcionar, parece que você está encontrando as limitações dessa versão do POI. A documentação diz:

> It might not work properly if the file contains Drawings or Charts. It also might fail if you try to write some styles.

Isso significa que ele pode falhar se adicionar imagens ou gráficos e também alguns tipos de estilos.

Você pode fazer um teste removendo o trecho que adiciona imagens do seu código. Se funcionar é porque infelizmente essa versão não suporta bem essas funcionalidades.

Comment: Fiz o teste mais continua com o erro, vou refazer o download das bibliotecas porém vou utilizar a versão normal sem modificações.

Comment: @MatheusArrudaLab Remove também o `poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-reduced-less`, ele deve ser redundante.

Comment: @MatheusArrudaLab Editei a resposta após ler com mais atenção a documentação.

Comment: não deu, atualizei a biblioteca para a versão 3.11 com todas as bibliotecas compatíveis com a versão e o erro continua o mesmo, se eu remover a parte da imagem o código funciona perfeitamente, mais estou gerando relatórios e essas fotos vão automaticamente pro relatório estou pensando em utilizar o jxls junto com o apache poi, faço todas as alterações no Apache salvo e abro novamente com o Jxls, amanha vou tentar e retorno aqui. Forte abraço, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Boa ideia usar o Jxls e boa sorte. :)